# How to hide a piece of code from a wordpress web page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugin

I installed a plugin called Sociable on my Wordpress website. It displays social media share icons below each blog post, but on my website it's also showing up in the footer. Like here http://amsa.mn/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3
I've been trying to figure out how to remove it from the footer for quite a while, but can't figure it out. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think what this plugin is doing is taking all the div level elements and sticking the sociable div inside them. Which works great, however your footer is getting pasted with the div as well!!

A workaround would be to add a custom CSS class to your themefiles which will render the sociable div in the footer invisible. Something like this -

.copyrights .sociable {
display:none !important;
}

However, there might be better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with that plugins settings but what you can do is use http://www.addthis.com copy the javascript snippet and place it into your single.php template file which is the file that displays your posts. That way they share icons are displayed only on your post page. You can place the code anywhere you want